# Jest: is it possible to automock an imported function?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs, mocking

I know it's possible to automock modules so that you don't have to create mock implementations for them.

Like this:

**file.test.js**

```
jest.mock('./my-player.js');

import myPlayer from './my-player'
```

so now `myPlayer` would be mocked already so I can use it.

---

But what about if I had a file where I was importing a function:

**other.test.js**

```
import { getData }  from './helpers';
```

do I have to create a mock implementation for that or is there a way to automock that?

Comment: https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#automock-boolean

Comment: I had to deal with this before, the only way I found was creating a manual mock in __mocks__ folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can auto-mock your helpers by calling `jest.mock` and then importing the functions you need for your tests i.e.

```
jest.mock('./helpers');
import { getData }  from './helpers';
```

jest.mock will auto-mock the functions exported.